# replace 2 escaped linefeeds / new lines "\n"

Tags: javascript, regex

How come I can replace one escaped newline `\n` from a text area with anything...

```
str1   = str1.replace(/\n /g,"7 ");
```

but it does not work with two of them?

```
str1   = str1.replace(/\n\n /g,"7 ");
```

I copied and decoded the lines and it shows up as `&#10;&#10;` so I know they are there.
It works fine with one... why not 2?

I also tried it with a space between them to no avail...

```
str1   = str1.replace(/\n \n/g,"7 ");
```

Comment: Remove the space *after* them.

Comment: this didn't work... it needed the `\r\n\r\n`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try with this..

```
str1   = str1.replace(/\r\n\r\n /g,"7 ");
```

A new line is basically a combination of **Carriage Return (\r)** & **Line Feed (\n)**

Comment: this works `str1.replace(/\r\n\r\n /g,"7 ");` and so does this `str1.replace(/\r\n\r\n/g,"7 ");`  thanks

Comment: Glad to hear!! Please mark this post as Answer as it worked. This will help in closing this thread.

Comment: they make you wait 5 minutes... it would have been done already.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!! Am new here.. :)

Comment: p.s. can you add the one with `\r\n\r\n` into your post... that is actually the correct answer. i.e. one is `\r\n` two is `\r\n\r\n`

Comment: add in, not change i.e. original was `\r\n` two is `\r\n\r\n` over an out

Answer (score 2):

instead of \n, you can use "System.Environment.NewLine"
e.g.

```
str1.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "7")
```

**EDIT:**

if you want to replace two line then you can simply add another

```
str1.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine, "7")
```

Comment: Bit I only wanted to replace if there are two of them together.

Comment: if you want two line then you can do System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine